# How to display just the group name of groups user is member of in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I have the following script but it lists the full name of the AD group. (e.g. `CN=GroupName,OU=OUName,DC=DomainName,DC=com`) How do I specify only the group's name, so that it lists only the name itself. The part after `CN=`. I tried `$group.Name` but no such luck.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$userlist = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\US_User_List.txt"

foreach ($username in $userlist) {
    $grplist = (Get-ADUser $username –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
    foreach ($group in $grplist) {
        write-host $group
    }
}
```

Also as a second question is there some way to filter based on what the group name starts with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look it up with `Get-ADGroup`

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$userlist = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\US_User_List.txt"

foreach ($username in $userlist) {
    $grplist = (Get-ADUser $username –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
    foreach ($group in $grplist) {
        (Get-ADGroup $group).name 
    }
}
```

For the second part, you can use a `Where-Object`/`?` filter.

```
$grplist = (Get-ADUser $username –Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | ? {$_ -like "CN=StartsWithExample*"}
```

Comment: That works but what if I want a second filter for like, if it starts with this OR that?

Comment: See my answer, which will probably be faster if you have a large number of users and/or group memberships.

Comment: That worked but now I'm trying to ignore specific names using a conditional statement, the -or isn't working, it only works when I don't use -or. Like if ($name.name -ne "Group_Name") { do this } but not if (($name.name -ne "Group_Name") -or ($name.name -ne "Group_Name")) { do this }

Comment: See my answer regarding the filter.

Comment: It would appear that this answer outputs a list of group names without any way of knowing which users are members of which groups. My answer doesn't suffer from this limitation.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That wasn't requested which was why it wasn't part of my answer. Verbatim: "How to display just the group name of groups user is member of"

Comment: @BenH - Understood - but in my experience, I already know that's going to be the next question <grin>

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
foreach ( $name in $names ) {
  Get-ADUser $name -Properties memberOf |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberOf |
    Get-ADPathname -Format Leaf -ValuesOnly |
    Where-Object { ($_ -like "this*") -or ($_ -like "that*") } |
    Sort-Object | 
    ForEach-Object {
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        "Name" = $name
        "memberOf" = $_
      }
    }
}
```

You can adjust the filter in the `Where-Object` scriptblock how you want it.

You can get the Get-ADPathname.ps1 script from here:

[Windows IT Pro - Use PowerShell to Handle Active Directory Paths](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-active-directory-paths)

A note on the `Where-Object` filter - if you want to say "groups whose names do not start with this or that", you would write it this way:

```
Where-Object { -not (($_ -like "this*") -or ($_ -like "that*")) }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple way : `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity blabla | Select-Object Name`

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership outputs the group objects a user is a member of and it comes with the default AD module.

Comment: That cmdlet is currently broken (it does not work if any of your group names contain a `/` character - an embarrassing bug for a MS cmdlet).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart wow, I was unaware of that bug (I've never encountered that one, but we always try to avoid "special characters" in groups (besides dashes, underscores and spaces) too keep it easier to automate stuff.

Comment: A slash is a perfectly valid character in AD object names.