# Powershell script pulling AD Users Group Memberships but CSV formatting a mess

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a csv file which contains the username and the group memberships from a list of usernames to a CSV file.

But the CSV file is formatted as below

```
******;"CN=Cal_ACABLHolidayCalendar_Editor
```

Username and group in 1 cell

```
$list = Get-Content c:\Tools\Powershell\ACA\userlist.txt
$list | `
    %{  
        $user = $_; 
        get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | `
        select -expand memberof | `
        %{new-object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}} `
    } |
export-csv –Path "C:\Tools\Powershell\ADUsers.csv" -Delimiter ‘;’ –NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

How can I have the formatting as the first cell with the username and the below cells with the groups

Comment: in a CSV file, each _row_ is an object & each column name is a property name & the value in each cell is the value for that property in that object. ///// please show [1] what you are getting & [2] how you WANT the output to be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Export-CSV` is the wrong way to achieve your desired solution.
You should be better with something like this:

```
$excelfile = "C:\Daten\test.xlsx"

###Excel Parameter###
$excel = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"    
$excel.displayalerts = $false
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.usercontrol = $false         
$Workbook=$excel.Workbooks.open($excelfile)     
$Worksheet=$Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Worksheet.Activate() | Out-null


$x = 1
$y = 1

$list = get-content c:\daten\list.txt
foreach ($user in $list){
 $groups = (get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof | %{new-object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}} | select -ExpandProperty Group)
 $z = $groups.count
 $excel.cells.item($y,$x) = $user
 for ($i = 2; $i -le $groups.count+1; $i++)
 {
 $excel.cells.item($i,$x) = $groups[$i]
 }
 $x=$x+1
}
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
get-process *excel* | kill -Force
```

Its not 100% correct. Something is wrong with the counter of the username. First user works good though.

Comment: Thanks Robin I am a real noob when it comes to powershell your script is working fine for me.

Comment: I have one further question on formatting currently the outlot looks like this CN=SophosHomeUsers,OU=Sophos,OU=Security-Groups,DC=rgu,DC=ac,DC=uk is there a way for the output to only display SophosHomeUsers or FS_ACABL_Fit4Energy_RW without the OU data and the CN= I hope this makes sence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123279/how-to-display-just-the-group-name-of-groups-user-is-member-of-in-powershell

This might help you getting only the group name. Unfortunately the memberof property only display the Canonical Name of the group.
You have to combine `Get-ADUser` and the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlets within an foreach as explained in the link above.

Comment: Thank You Robin you pointed me in the direction I required I have now been able to generate the output to the excel file that I required many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that @Scott